# Java MapReduce job to calculate the percentage

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Below is my Table (MyTable)

```
ID          TotalCount   ErrorCount   DT
----------------------------------------------
1345653         5           3       20120709
534140349       5           2       20120709
601806615       5           1       20120709
682527813       4           3       20120709
687612723       3           2       20120709
704318001       5           4       20120709
1345653         5           2       20120710
704318001       1           0       20120710
1120784094      3           2       20120711
```

So If I need to calculate the error percentage in Hive using HiveQL for specific date, then I will be doing like this-

```
SELECT 100 * sum(ErrorCount*1.0) / sum(TotalCount) FROM MyTable 
where dt = '20120709';
```

But I need to do the same thing using `Java MapReduce`. Is there any way we can do the same thing using `MapReduce in Java code`. First of all I am confused whenever we write any MapReduce job in Java we read the corresponding file for that date partition? or we read the table?

**Update:-**
Below is the table name which will contain the above scenario

```
create table lipy
( buyer_id bigint,
  total_chkout bigint,
  total_errpds bigint
 )
 partitioned by (dt string)
row format delimited fields terminated by '\t'
stored as sequencefile
location '/apps/hdmi-technology/lipy'
;
```

Comment: If you do not mind asking, why do you need to implement this in Java MapReduce. HiveQL gets translated to MapReduce code anyway.

Comment: I wanted to do this in Java MapReduce because I need to generate a report basis on that `percentage` I will be getting as mentioned in the query. So I thought may be if I am doing in Java MapReduce, then I can make an excel report as a Graph showing percentage thing and then also I can send that excel file as an email in an attachment to my teams. That is the reason I wanted to do it in Java MapReduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is quite easy- let me give a shot at some pseudo code.

```
SELECT 100 * sum(ErrorCount*1.0) / sum(TotalCount) FROM MyTable 
where dt = '20120709';
```

Map Stage:

- increment a counter for total counts (you can simply use a field)
- check if the `dt` column is equal to `20120709`
- if yes, increment an error counter
- in cleanup emit as `Key/Value`: `-1 / totalcount` and `0 / error counter`

Reduce stage:
 (you get a totalcount for key -1 and the error counter as key 0)

- add all the numbers from key -1 and key 0
- in cleanup you can calculate your percentage, and maybe send a mail if that is possible

Several things to note:

- Mapoutput is `<IntWritable, IntWritable>` or `<IntWritable,LongWritable>` if the count does not fit in a integer.
- Set the number of reducers to 1, so a single reducer gets all the keys.

I believe this is everything to note, it is quite early here and I had no coffee, so if you find a problem, feel free to tell me ;)

Comment: Thanks Thomas for suggestion. I recently started working with MapReduce so I am not sure how can I start implementing the above pseudo code you provided me. Can you provide me some code example that will work considering my scenario. And I have also updated my question with the table structure. It will be of great help if you can provide some working code, by that I can understand more on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but the implementation will depend on:

1. Are your tables external
   About locations:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintofilesystemfromqueries

1. How is data formatted - row format, delimited, ...
   http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.9.0/language_manual/data-manipulation-statements.html
2. How do you want to execute MapReduce. One very straightforward option is to run your 
   Java MapReduce code as user defined functions (UDFs) that reuse HiveQL functions:

https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/tutorial.html#Tutorial-Custommap%252Freducescripts

or simply run your custom mapreduce over Hive table data in HDFS.

Comment: I have updated the question with my Table Structure that will be storing that data. Can you provide me some example by that way I can understand more.